# Using Regex for Require Statemens in htacces

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a directory (`path/to/directory/`) in which there is a .htacces blocking access using `Require valid-user` to require an authentication.
Now my task is to allow access to a subdirectory(`path/to/director/foobar`) and anything that might be in that subdirectory.
I do know how to grant access to a specific file by matching the request with the file path.
However, I do not know how the structure will look inside the directory.

I was wondering if it may be possible to check with a regular expression for the name of my directory?
so I considered

```
<RequireANY>
  #Allow subdirectory
  Require %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?(\bfoobar\b)[^$]*)$

  #fallback
  Require valid-user
</RequireANY>
```

The regex checks out in https://regex101.com/ to match any URI, with `foobar` in it. Sadly the condition does not work like that. Did I miss something important as I am fairly unfamiliar with .htacces.? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You may use this block with `<if>` expression:

```sh
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/path/to/directory/(?!foobar/)#">
  <RequireANY>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Secret Area"
    AuthUserFile /full/path/of/passwords/file
    Require valid-user
  </RequireANY>
</If>
```

Negative lookahead regex pattern `^/path/to/directory/(?!foobar/)` will match `/path/to/directory/*` except when `foobar/` comes directly after it.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution to to exactly what I needed. I found it in an Installation Guide for Shopware 6 `https://docs.shopware.com/de/shopware-6-de/erste-schritte/shopware-6-installieren`

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Please login."
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd

<RequireAny>
    Require expr %{THE_REQUEST} =~ m#.*?\s+\/foobar.*?#
    Require valid-user
</RequireAny>
```

Comment: This is adding password protection for anything that has `/foobar` in it. This is now what you've asked in question. Where does it put `/path/to/directory/` behind password protection?